# Yii2 Запрос со сложной связью

Tags: sql, yii2

Вообщем у меня есть сайт на yii2. Там на одной странице я вывожу, некоторые данные, запрос который я собираю выглядит так:

```
SELECT `cycle`.* 
FROM `cycle` 
LEFT JOIN `company` ON `cycle`.`company_id` = `company`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `deadline` ON (`company`.`id` = `deadline`.`company_id`) 
                    AND (`deadline`.`year`='cycle.year') 
WHERE `cycle`.`id`='166'
```

Грубо говоря я в "циклах" (это если что название странички), тащу название компнии, связанные с дедлайны, при этом самых дедланов очень много, но мне нужно вытащить только с определенным годом, как видно  из запросах, год я беру из цикла. Запрос в таком виде не работает, как мне его переделать, чтобы он начал работать? Просто фильтровать все дедлайны после получения такая себе идея.

Да код для запроса выглядит так:

```
$cycle = Cycle::find()->joinWith(['company.simplyDeadlines' => function ($query) {
     $query->onCondition([Deadline::tableName() . '.year' => Cycle::tableName() . '.year']);
}])->where([Cycle::tableName() . '.id' => $id])->asArray()->one();
```

Comment: В условии ```AND (`deadline`.`year`='cycle.year')``` подозрительно странные кавычки.

Comment: @Akina Да действительно из-за этих странных ковычек получается что он сверяет не со столбиком, а со строкой, если заставить её сверять со столбиком то заработает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте переписать так:

```
SELECT `cycle`.* 
FROM `cycle` 
LEFT JOIN `company` ON `cycle`.`company_id` = `company`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `deadline` ON `company`.`id` = `deadline`.`company_id`                    
WHERE `cycle`.`id`='166'
  AND (`deadline`.`year`=`cycle`.`year` OR `deadline`.`year` IS NULL) 
-- или
-- AND COALESCE(`deadline`.`year`,`cycle`.`year`) = `cycle`.`year`
```

или

```
SELECT `cycle`.* 
FROM `cycle` 
LEFT JOIN `company` ON `cycle`.`company_id` = `company`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `deadline` ON `company`.`id` = `deadline`.`company_id` 
                    AND `deadline`.`year`=`cycle`.`year`                   
WHERE `cycle`.`id`='166'
```

Comment: не так не робит, вообще пустоту получаю

Comment: @Moonwolf45 ну нет так нет (хотя обязано - ибо полный эквивалент).

Comment: Я нашел как он работает, но выдаёт всё равно полный список дедлайнов
Вот так робит: `$cycle = Cycle::find()->joinWith('company.simplyDeadlines')->where([Cycle::tableName() . '.id' => $id])->andWhere(new Expression('`' . Deadline::tableName() . '`.`year` = `' . Cycle::tableName() . '`.`year`'))->asArray()->one();` Так он строит правильный код, но он не даёт нужно результата, блин тут кавычки не показываются, но суть думаю понятна

Comment: @Moonwolf45 в строке обрамляйте код тройным бэктиком.

Comment: @Moonwolf45 В запросе у Вас LEFT JOIN, а в коде почему-то ни фига не left...

Comment: Вот так: `$cycle = Cycle::find()->joinWith('company.simplyDeadlines')->where([Cycle::tableName() . '.id' => $id])->andWhere(new Expression('\`' . Deadline::tableName() . '\`.\`year\` = \`' . Cycle::tableName() . '\`.\`year\`'))->asArray()->one();`

Comment: Yii2 по умолчанию строит через left join тот код что сверху в sql выглядит так:
`SELECT \`cycle\`.* FROM \`cycle\` LEFT JOIN \`company\` ON \`cycle\`.\`company_id\` = \`company\`.\`id\` LEFT JOIN \`deadline\` ON (\`company\`.\`id\` = \`deadline\`.\`company_id\`) WHERE \`cycle\`.\`id\`='166' AND (\`deadline\`.\`year\`=\`cycle\`.\`year\`)`

Comment: Вот этот фрагмент: ```WHERE ... (`deadline`.`year`=`cycle`.`year`)``` немедленно превращает LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN. Используйте вариант, который я показываю.

Comment: Я могу построить такой код, вот только он ручками мне не нежен поскольку когда я использую joinWith у меня тащатся связи которые мне нужны именно поэтому, я руками leftjoin не делаю, потому что так связи не тянутся ((

Comment: Тогда выворачивайтесь, чтобы это условие было не во WHERE, а в ON. Ща добавлю в текст ответа... готово.

Comment: Я уже добавлял в он в итоге когда он делает связывающий запрос вот, возникает проблема с отсутствием столбика:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cycle.year' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM \`deadline\` WHERE (\`company_id\`='1') AND (\`deadline\`.\`year\` = \`cycle\`.\`year\`)` поэтому я думаю выгаднее сделать 2 запрос, который вытащит мне то что надо.

Comment: Что-то ты куда-то не туда походу добавлял, что у тебя опять условие во WHERE попало...

Comment: Нет, добавлял я в нужное место, просто joinWith, генерирует еще 2 запроса, один тащит компанию, а второй тащит дедлайны связанные с этой компанией, а я добавил чтобы он еще все это дело сравнивал с годом который стоит у цикла, но он не меняет названия столбика на перменную, и поэтому вылизает ошибка, что отсутствует такой-то столбик

Comment: @Moonwolf45 Просто по моему разумению должно быть что-то типа ```$query->onCondition(..)->onCondition(..)```, и в каждой скобке связывание с одной из таблиц по одному из условий - хотя, конечно, фиг знает, как на самом деле. А попробовать мне негде.